# How do i rotate a window in xCode 4 interface builder tool thing?

Tags: xcode, ios4

I can't seem to find it. I know xCode 3 had a button to rotate on the view. I want to make the App Landscape. Any idea how?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Open the **Attributes inspector** from utilities sidebar (Cmd+Alt+4). You'll see the "Orientation" setting there.

Comment: Thanks... For me its graded out. I'm am such an xCode noob. Trying to get in to iOS development coming from Php.

Comment: Don't sweat it. It's pretty well hidden for me as experienced Xcode 3 user too!

Comment: What if the Orientation dropdown is disabled? How can it be enabled?

Answer (score 1):

You mean the iPhone simulator?
if so, click anywhere on the simulator, the see the menu, select device, you'll see rotate to left, rotate to right.
I am not using an English simulator, so I am not sure about the name of the menu item, but i'm sure you'll be easy to find it.