# Rotate view in xib file to landscape mode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, xcode4, landscape

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do i rotate a window in xCode 4 interface builder tool thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327927/how-do-i-rotate-a-window-in-xcode-4-interface-builder-tool-thing)

Is it possible to rotate :

[image]

to landscape mode.  I want my application to just support landscape mode therefore it will be easier if I could work on landscape mode with Xcode. I know how to rotate the view on the iPhone and iPad simulator but I actually want to rotate it in Xcode.

Comment: Here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327927/how-do-i-rotate-a-window-in-xcode-4-interface-builder-tool-thing

Answer (score 16):

It's under the Simulated Metrics section of the Attributes view.

[image: Set the Orientation drop down to portrait]